# How to trigger a button in Parent component from Child component. Angular 10+

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding

1. Emit value from child component to the parent
2. In the parent component handle the function and trigger button in the template

My Structure
Child component

```
export class ChildComponent {
 @Output() selectCustomer = new EventEmitter<Customer>();

 onSelectCustomer(customer: Customer) {
        this.selectCustomer.emit(customer);
 }
}
```

So once the child component selects the Customer from the List of Items I want to handle it in parent component. ***#btnToTrigger***

```
<parent-component>
...
   <child-component
     (selectCustomer)=selectCustomer($event)>  <-- emits value
   </child-component>
...
   <button #btnToTrigger>Continue</button> <--How to trigger this button after child component emits value in controller?
</parent-component>
```

Parent Component Controller

```
export class ParentComponent {
     ...
    
     selectCustomer(customer: Customer) {
           console.log(customer);
           //Value Emited, but how to trigger button in same component template from here?
           //#btnToTrigger
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `#btnToTrigger` reference to `selectCustomer` method as:

```html
<child-component
    (selectCustomer)=selectCustomer($event, btnToTrigger)>
</child-component>
<button #btnToTrigger (click)="onClick()">Continue</button>
```

and then use the same within your `selectCustomer` method to trigger the click:

```ts
selectCustomer(customer: Customer, buttonElement: HTMLButtonElement) {
  console.log(customer);
  buttonElement.click();
}
```